# Storing only return value of function

Tags: python, function, return

When a function has print statement and return some value, For example,

```
def func(n):
    print('want to ignore')
    return 2*n
```

I want to store the return value without executing print phrase. Like,

```
>>> a = ???(func(5))
>>> a
10
```

Is it possible? If so, please help me! Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a global variable by considering its drawback would help you.

Comment: Yes, comment out the print statement.

Comment: On a more serious note, this is actually possible, but not easy... see the referenced question, and also [here](http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2012/10/25/temporarily-suppress-console-output-in-python/). Furthermore, if you're using IPython, the `%%capture` magic makes this easier.